# Positioning relative to an element and window

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, modal-dialog

I currently have a dialog with a bunch of options defined. It is shown when the user clicks on a button. My dialog is defined as:

```js
    $('#newIssueDialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        closeOnEscape: true,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        width: 415,
        height: 175,
        position: {my: "top", at: "bottom", of: "#btnNewIssue"}
    });
```

This pops my dialog up, centered below my button.
What I'd actually like to do is pop the dialog below the button, but centered on my *window*.

Any ideas on how to do that?

Edit: Also, is it possible to take into account the position of the window relative to the document? As in, if there are scrollbars on the page and the user has scrolled the page vertically or horizontally, can we calculate the position of the button and where we are on the page so that it is still below the button and centered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `my, at, of` you can calculate the position yourself for the `left` and `top` like this:

```
$("#btnNewIssue").on("click", function() {
    var $button = $(this);
    var $dialog = $('#newIssueDialog');

    //var top = $button.position().top + $button.height() + ($button.outerHeight() / 2);
    var top = $button.position().top + $button.height() + (($button.outerHeight(true) - $button.height()));
    var left = ($(document).width() - ($dialog.outerWidth / 2)) / 2

    $dialog.dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        modal: true,
        closeOnEscape: true,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        width: 415,
        height: 175,
        position: [left, top]
    });
});​
```

Using the basic HTML as example:

```
<div id="newIssueDialog"> My modal dialog</div>
<button id="btnNewIssue">Click Me</button>
```

​

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/x6nRV/) - Positioning dialog below button but centred of window/document

I'm using `document` in the example above but you can use window instead if you want, there should be little to no difference.

**Edit**

Fixed an oversight whereby the border height, the padding and margin of the button was not included correctly.

I saved the fiddle without adding the deduction of the `height` from `outerHeight(true)` to include  the `borders`, `padding` and `margins` of the button as well in case the button had any specified.

This:

```
var top = $button.position().top + $button.height() + ($button.outerHeight() / 2);
```

Should be this:

```
var top = $button.position().top + $button.height() + (($button.outerHeight(true) - $button.height()));
```

Demo has been updated as well.

**Edit**

> However, I'm now running into an issue if scrollbars are present on
>   the page.

For the vertical scroll position, just deduct the current `scrollTop()` value at the end like this:

```
var top = $button.position().top + $button.height() + ($button.outerHeight(true) - $button.height()) - $(window).scrollTop();
```

For placing the modal in the middle horizontally you don't need to change anything. The above code to calculate `left` seems to always work. **However** if it is an issue for you in your specific markup, please have a look at [**scrollLeft()**](http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/) which I would assume would work the same way in that you need to deduct it similar to:

```
var left = (($(document).width() - ($dialog.outerWidth / 2)) / 2) - $(window).scrollLeft();
```

or possibly

```
var left = ($(window).scrollLeft() - $(document).width() - ($dialog.outerWidth / 2)) / 2;
```

As said, the DEMO below doesn't need it but if you do, move it around and see how it fits in.

> Please note that if your button is close to the bottom of the screen
>   the modal will **not** be below the button as it cannot be off-screen
>   but it will align the bottom of the dialog with the bottom of the
>   screen instead. That is expected behaviour. You see though that if the
>   button has enough room below it the dialog will always be as expected,
>   just below the button.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/G8tnz/) - Including window scroll position
***(You need to scroll down to get to the button and you can also scroll to the right to test it properly)***

Comment: Might I suggest removing button.height and simply use `var top = $button.position().top + $button.outerHeight(true);` instead? It seems that `outerHeight` will already do everything you need for getting the height of the button.

Comment: @Ellesedil: Sorry about that, seems I had saved my fiddle prematurely forgetting to deduct the `height` properly form the `outerHeight(true)` before the divison. The reason those are there is to ensure any `borders`, `margins` or `padding` the buttons has are considered when positioning the `top` of the dialog.

Comment: @Ellesedil: Had a few logicals to work out but now if you apply the margins and padding to the button they are also considered in the `top` calculation.

Comment: Although I've modified this approach a bit to suit my needs, this is working fairly well. I like it because I do not need to define the expected heights/widths. However, I'm now running into an issue if scrollbars are present on the page. I've udpated my question to reflect that.

Comment: @Ellesedil: See my edit. I have added the deduction of `$(window).scrollTop()` to calculate the proper `top` value if the screen is scrolled. For the `left` value there should be no change as seen in the DEMO. Please see the note on the dialog position if your button is to close to the bottom of the screen, not leaving enough room for the dialog to be displayed. The dialog will not be below the button but instead be flush with the bottom of the screen, which is expected behaviour to prevent the modal from initially being displayed outside the viewport. I hope this helps.

Comment: @Ellesedil: Though the DEMO didn't have issues with the `left` value, if you do find you have an issue, have a look at `scrollLeft()` and include that somehow. I edited my answer to add the comment regarding it, just in-case.

Comment: No, it looks fine. I'm actually trying to declare the position within the definition of the dialog (rather than outside of it like the answers present). I have a custom option to automatically re-position the dialog when the window is resized, so I need to have access to the updated heights/widths. However, for some reason, `$(document).scrollTop()` (and window as well) returns a negative number when declare there, even though it works correctly in, say, an alert. Thanks for helping me get this far, though.

Answer (score 0):

The best that I can come up with is that you are going to have to specify the X/Y coordinates yourself when opening the dialog.

```
$("#btnNewIssue").button().click(function(){
    var x = ($(window).width() - 415) / 2;
    var y = $(this).offset().top + $(this).height();
    $("#newIssueDialog").dialog("option", "position", [x,y]).dialog("open");
});​
```

[Demo JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dx3Wj/1/)